# Pandas - split columns and count occurrences

Tags: pandas, count

It's info for some purchases made by clients on phone accessories, my real data would look something like this: 
`Abstract Model 1 ~Samsung S6 | Sold: 4`

I've got a dataset that looks something like this:

```
item               sold
Design1 ~Model1 1
Design2 ~Model1 2
Design1 ~Model2 3
Design2 ~Model2 1
```

I want to break the `item` column into 2 columns , `design` and `model`, and count each time a `design` has been sold, and a `model` has been sold, individually, based on the selling data of design+model combinations in the input.

My expected output, based on the first dataset, would look something like this:

```
expected output:        

design    design_sold    model      model_sold

Design1   4              Model1     3
Design2   3              Model2     4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
df[['Design','Model']]=df['item'].str.split(' ~',expand=True)
print pd.concat([df.groupby('Design',as_index=False)['sold'].sum().rename(columns={'sold':'Desgin Sold'}),df.groupby('Model',as_index=False)['sold'].sum().rename(columns={'sold':'Model Sold'})],axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    Design  Desgin Sold   Model  Model Sold
0  Design1            4  Model1           3
1  Design2            3  Model2           4
```

Explanation:'
1. `.str.split()` used to split your series into frame.

2. `groupby` model and design and perform `sum` on grouped object.
3. `rename` the column and `concat` your dataframe.

Comment: Hello, Mohamed;

Thank you for your reply;

I'm currently getting a syntax error on the last line, trying to figure it out exactly where it is, as we speak

Comment: This above code works nicely to me, try your self let me know if you still stuck... Happy coding 

Comment: It did work, I had to assign the result to the Dataframe instead of printing it. 
Thank you so much for this, man, you're the best!